# How to add custom theme features of post into custom post type? Wordpress, php

Tags: php, wordpress

i created a custom post type but i only get default support features like thumbnails, exerpt etc but what i want is to add all extra features of ceris theme in posts into my custom post type can you help me out?

```
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'directory', 'Ceris' ),
    'description'         => __( 'directory all posts', 'Ceris' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt','thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields','post-formats','page-attributes','bk_review_score' ),
    // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'posts' ),
    /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
    * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
    * is like Posts.
    */ 
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'show_in_rest' => true,

);
```

check my support array like i'm trying to add bk_review_system into my cpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do it

try the following code, BK come with a filter to add widget and there configuration

```php
function bk_child_register_meta_boxes($meta_boxes) {
        $meta_boxes[] = array(
            'id' => 'bk_review',
            'title' => esc_html__( 'BK Review System', 'ceris' ),
            'pages' => array( 'directory' ),
            'context' => 'normal',
            'priority' => 'high',
            
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'heading',
                    'name' => esc_html__('Author Review', 'ceris'),
                    'desc' => esc_html__('This section allow you to give your review, pros, cons', 'ceris'),
                ),
                
                // Enable Review
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Review Box', 'ceris' ),
                    'id' => 'bk_review_checkbox',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'desc' => esc_html__( 'Enable Review On This Post', 'ceris' ),
                    'std'  => 0,
                ),
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 'bk_review_box_position',
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Review Box Position', 'ceris' ),
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options'  => array(
                        'default'      => esc_html__( 'Default -- Under the post content', 'ceris' ),
                        'top'          => esc_html__( 'On top of the post content ', 'ceris' ),
                    ),
                    // Select multiple values, optional. Default is false.
                    'multiple'    => false,
                    'std'         => 'default',
                    'visible'     => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Product Image',
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_product_img',
                    'type' => 'single_image',
                    'visible'     => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Product name', 'ceris' ),
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_box_title',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Description', 'ceris' ),
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_box_sub_title',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                //Review Score
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Review Score', 'ceris' ),
                    'id' => 'bk_review_score',
                    'class' => 'ceris-',
                    'type' => 'slider',
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'js_options' => array(
                        'min'   => 0,
                        'max'   => 10.05,
                        'step'  => .1,
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                // Summary
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Summary', 'ceris' ),
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_summary',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'rows' => 4,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                ),
                
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                
                //Pros & Cons
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Pros and Cons', 'ceris' ),
                    'id' => 'bk_pros_cons',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'desc' => esc_html__( 'Enable Pros and Cons On This Post', 'ceris' ),
                    'std'  => 0,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_pros_cons', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Pros Title', 'ceris' ),
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_pros_title',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_pros_cons', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Pros (Advantages)', 'ceris' ),
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_pros',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'clone' => true,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_pros_cons', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_pros_cons', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Cons Title', 'ceris' ),
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_cons_title',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_pros_cons', '=', 1),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Cons (Disadvantages)', 'ceris' ),
                    'id'   => 'bk_review_cons',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'clone' => true,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_pros_cons', '=', 1),
                ),
                
                array(
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'heading',
                    'name' => esc_html__('Performance and User Review', 'ceris'),
                    'desc' => esc_html__('This section allow you to have some criterias and allow your reader to share their review', 'ceris'),
                ),
                
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Performance and User Review Check Box', 'ceris' ),
                    'id' => 'bk_performance_review_checkbox',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'desc' => esc_html__( 'Enable This Review', 'ceris' ),
                    'std'  => 0,
                ),
                array(
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_performance_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                array(
                    'id'     => 'bk_performance_review_score_criteria_group',
                    // Group field
                    'type'   => 'group',
                    // Clone whole group?
                    'clone'  => true,
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_performance_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    // Sub-fields
                    'fields' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => esc_html__( 'Criteria Title', 'ceris' ),
                            'id'   => 'review_criteria_title',
                            'type' => 'text',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => esc_html__( 'Criteria Score', 'ceris' ),
                            'id' => 'review_criteria_score',
                            'class' => 'ceris-',
                            'type' => 'slider',
                            'js_options' => array(
                                'min'   => 0,
                                'max'   => 10.05,
                                'step'  => .1,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                
                array(
                    'type' => 'divider',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => esc_html__( 'Reader Review Form', 'ceris' ),
                    'id' => 'bk_reader_review_checkbox',
                    'visible' => array( 'bk_performance_review_checkbox', '=', 1),
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'desc' => esc_html__( 'Enable Reader Review', 'ceris' ),
                    'std'  => 0,
                ),
            )
        );
        return $meta_boxes;
    }
    add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'bk_child_register_meta_boxes', 999,1 );
```

Comment: no problem I am glad that I was able to help, can you mark the question as answered?